# Send TERM signal to child process spawned in another thread of parent process

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl, signals, multiprocessing

I'm on Linux platform and using Perl. First of all I created a thread, and forked a child process in this new thread. When the parent in the new thread returned and joined to the main thread, I would like to send TERM signal to the child process spawned in the created thread, but the signal handler doesn't work, and the child process becomes zombie. Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Thread 'async';
use POSIX;

my $thrd = async {
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid == 0) {
        $SIG{TERM} = \&child_exit;
        `echo $$ > 1`;
        for (1..5) {
            print "in child process: cycle $_\n";
            sleep 2;
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        $SIG{CHLD} = \&reaper;
    }
};

$thrd->detach();
sleep 4;
my $cpid = `cat 1`;
kill "TERM", $cpid;
while (1) {}

sub child_exit {
    print "child $$ exits!\n";
    exit(0);
}

sub reaper {
    my $pid;
    while (($pid = waitpid(-1, &WNOHANG)) > 0) {
        print "reaping child process $pid\n";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions about how to successfully and safely send signal in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you saying that the SIGTERM handler does not work?  Because the child becomes a zombie?

All children process become zombies unless you wait for them.  Put `waitpid($pid, 0);` after the `kill()`.  Unless you see `in child process: cycle 5` in your printout, the kill and the signal handler are working just fine.

Note that it's super shaky to use a hardcoded file to communicate between your forked process and your main process.  I'd recommend you use a pipe.

Edit:

Wrt your sig handler not being called, I think this is a perl bug.  perl sends signals only to the main thread.  When you fork(), your thread becomes the main thread but I think perl does not realize that.  You can work this around though by re-forwarding the signal to yourself.

Before you create the threads, just add:

```
sub sigforwarder {
    threads->self()->kill(shift);
}
$SIG{TERM} = \&sigforwarder;
```

That *should* fix your problem

Comment: Thanks, the hardcoded file is just a simplified version of database, so this program is a simple model for part of my web app, which uses databases to store the pids. For the zombie part, sorry it's my bad, I forgot to add the reaper function, but in my web app I did install the handler for CHLD signal. I'm just wondering why the `print "child $$ exits!\n";` doesn't work and why the child didn't send CHLD signal to parent.

Comment: I edited the question by adding a reaper in the program. But it's not called anyway.

Comment: I didn't quite get it... Isn't that an endless recursion? `sigforwarder` catches a `TERM` signal, and re-send a `TERM` signal to child, then `sigforwarder` is called again.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it .  As I said above, I am not quite sure what you're seeing is not a bug in perl.  perl does not seem to realize there is only one thread in the child process and seems to behave like there is 2.  The sigforwarder just allows a "child thread" to get the signal.  perl will run the process signal handler only when the signal is received and the thread sig handler after you forward, so there is no recursion.
Note that you could simply fix the problem by forking in your main thread, and not in a child thread

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try to find a work around for my program, instead of forking on the child thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that child_exit does not perform any exit on the parent thread. It just exits the child. I don't know exactly what's happening in perl (just stumbled upon a fork/exec-construction in c), but I would try to catch SIG_CHILD in the parent process to detect its termination.

(the message "child $$ exits" is output in the child's 1, so it will not be visible on screen, right?)

EDIT: I just tried your example and I think I got it: You are performing a fork in the child process and check for the pid to be 0 (which is the parent async-Process). You might just check for != 0.

Comment: The child's 1 is in fact STDOUT, normally it would print out the message. I think different platforms with different thread models may have different behaviors, very curious about what happened inside...