# Is there a way to allow multiple connections to Dancer2

Tags: perl, dancer

My program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Dancer2;

$| = 1;

set host => '127.0.0.1';
set port => 7071;

get '/foo' => sub {
    `sleep 5`;
    'ok'
};

start;
```

Then I am run the following `for` loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3)
> do
>   time curl http://localhost:7071/foo &
> done
```

Output:

```
ok
real    0m5.032s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.000s
ok
real    0m10.037s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s
ok
real    0m15.043s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

It seems to Dancer2 can only accept one request one time, how to allow multiple connections to Dancer2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dancer: deal with multiple requests simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584501/dancer-deal-with-multiple-requests-simultaneously)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl programs are generally single-threaded. If you want to handle multiple things at the same time, you need to manage that explicitly.

- You can run multiple instances of your Dancer app. When one instance is busy, the other instances can still handle requests. Some servers automatically support such “pre-forking”, for example `Starman`. This is the classic solution to your problem, coupled with the observation that your backend shouldn't do lots of stuff that block execution.
- You can explicitly write your app to work asynchronously. Your `sleep` invocation is blocking the entire process, but you could also use libraries that let you resume handling of a request when some event occurs. For example, the Dancer2 docs show examples for using the `AnyEvent` timers.

If you are familiar with the Express web framework in JavaScript, it generally uses the second approach: NodeJS doesn't let you block the process by sleeping, and instead requires you to use promises (async/await) or callbacks to explicitly account for asynchronous execution.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/dist/Dancer2/view/lib/Dancer2/Manual/Deployment.pod is a good read.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon)'s suggestion, I have resolve the problem with the following code(foo.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Dancer2;

$| = 1;

get '/foo' => sub {
    `sleep 5`;
    'ok';
};

to_app;
```

And run the program as:

```
$ plackup -s Starman foo.pl
Resolved [*]:5000 to [0.0.0.0]:5000, IPv4
Binding to TCP port 5000 on host 0.0.0.0 with IPv4
Setting gid to "0 0 0"
Starman: Accepting connections at http://*:5000/
```

Then I am run the following `for` loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 3)
> do
>   time curl http://localhost:5000/foo &
> done
```

Output:

```
ok
real    0m5.077s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.010s
ok
real    0m5.079s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.012s
ok
real    0m5.097s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Now Dancer2 can accept multiple request.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I setup a dancer app, used plackup and Starman so a PSGI interface is provided.

```
cd $APP_DIR    
$PLACKUP -E $ENV -s Starman  --workers=20 -p 9000 \
                     -a bin/app.pl 2>&1 >  $LOGFILE &
```

There is a reverse proxy in front of the perl to handle static files faster and provide some anti-cracking protections in more commonly used tools for the Perl-deficient.

simbabque's answer is better. It shows this and other options.